# Find $[z^n]$ of a given EGF

Tags: recurrence-relations, power-series, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

I am stuck trying to find $[z^n]$ of the following EGF:

$$Â(z) = e^{z + z^2}$$

Well, I know this is a convolution between $e^z$ and $e^{z^2}$. So, we can rewrite it as

$$Â(z) = e^z.e^{z^2}$$

Finding the $nth$ term is

$$n![z^n](e^z.e^{z^2}) = n!(\sum_{k=0}^n[z^k]e^{z^2} . [z^{n-k}]e^z)$$

Writing down $e$ as a series

$$n![z^n](e^z.e^{z^2}) = n!\sum_{k=0}^n([z^k](\frac{z^0}{0!} + \frac{z^2}{1!} + \frac{z^4}{2!} + \frac{z^6}{3!} ...) . [z^{n-k}](\frac{z^0}{0!} + \frac{z^1}{1!} + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + ...))$$

Which I think is

$$n![z^n](e^z.e^{z^2}) = n!\sum_{k=0}^n(\frac{(1^k + (-1)^k)}{2(\frac{k}{2}!)} . \frac{1}{(n-k)!})$$

Is this right? I feel like I am doing something wrong here..

Comment: The first few terms of this sequence appear to be $1,1,3,7,25,81,331,\ldots$; you should probably check to see if your formula reproduces these. Furthermore, this matches the sequence [A047974](https://oeis.org/A047974) in the OEIS, and indeed it mentions on that page that it has the desired EGF. The formula you give appears to match that provided by Paul Barry in Feb 11 2008, also listed on that page.

Comment: @Semiclassical Indeed it matches Paul's formula. Thanks for the hint.